# Does GCP (Google Cloud Platform) support SignalR?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, signalr

We have a cloud product written in ASP.NET Core. This product is using SignalR for frontend/backend communication. This cloud product is being hosted in AKS (Azure).  Right now, we also need to host this product on GCP. Does GCP support SignalR for backend/frontend communication? Again, the product is written in ASP.NET Core.

Comment: GCP supports ASP.NET Core through Docker/Container images. SignalR depends on WebSockets and SSE and AFAIK those are supported by Google's HTTP infrastructure: https://console.cloud.google.com/marketplace/details/google/aspnetcore?pli=1

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it does.
You can deploy ASP.NET applications on [Compute Engine](https://cloud.google.com/dotnet/docs/getting-started/getting-started-on-compute-engine), [Cloud Run](https://cloud.google.com/dotnet/docs/getting-started) or [App Engine](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/dotnet).
You can find more information [here](https://medium.com/net-core/deploy-an-asp-net-core-app-to-google-cloud-d5ff3ff99b2d) and [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/dotnet/using-websockets-and-session-affinity).